# Google cloud deploy function with "allow unauthenticated" in python

Tags: python, authentication, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am deploying a Google Cloud Function from another Cloud Function with Python. See my code below:

```
import requests
import json


def make_func(request):


    # Get the access token from the metadata server
    metadata_server_token_url = 'http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/token?scopes=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'
    token_request_headers = {'Metadata-Flavor': 'Google'}
    token_response = requests.get(metadata_server_token_url, headers=token_request_headers)
    token_response_decoded = token_response.content.decode("utf-8")
    jwt = json.loads(token_response_decoded)['access_token']

    # Use the api to create the function
    response = requests.post('https://cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/v1/projects/myproject/locations/us-central1/functions',
                               json={"name":"projects/my-project/locations/us-central1/functions/funct","runtime":"python37","sourceArchiveUrl":"gs://bucket/main.zip","entryPoint":"hello_world","httpsTrigger": {} },
                               headers={'Accept': 'application/json', 
                                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                                        'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(jwt)} )   
    if response:
         return 'Success! Function Created'
    else:
         return str(response.json())
```

However this function does not have "allow unauthenticated" on automatically. Thus, no requests from outside are allowed. How can I change my Python code to add this functionality when deploying the new function?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to additionally give the `allUsers` member the `Cloud Functions Invoker` role:

```py
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
service = build('cloudfunctions', 'v1')

project_id = ...
location_id = ...
function_id = ...
resource = f'projects/{project_id}/locations/{location_id}/functions/{function_id}'

set_iam_policy_request_body = {
    'policy': {
        "bindings": [
            {
              "role": "roles/cloudfunctions.invoker",
              "members": ["allUsers"],
            },
        ],
    },
}

request = service.projects().locations().functions().setIamPolicy(
    resource=resource,
    body=set_iam_policy_request_body,
)
response = request.execute()

print(response)
```

This uses the [`google-api-python-client`](https://pypi.org/project/google-api-python-client/) package.

Comment: Do you know how I can do this in Python?

Comment: There's an example in Python here: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.roles/create

Comment: Thanks. But this is to create a role in the project right? How do I bind it to the function I created?

Comment: Updated my answer with a complete example. You can also use this API service to deploy the function instead of manually getting the tokens and creating an HTTP request: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.functions/create

Comment: @SiemPeters, no, it binds on the function. Look at the resource name `projects/{project_id}/locations/{location_id}/functions/{function_id}`. It's not all the functions of the project, only this one with the function_id in the defined location

Answer (score 1):

In addition of Dustin answer, you have to know that the `--allow-unauthenticated` is for developer convenience. Under the hood it perform 2 things

- Deploy your function in private mode
- Add allUsers as member with Cloudfunction.invoker role

```
gcloud functions add-iam-policy-binding --member=allUsers --role=roles/cloudfunctions.invoker function-1
```

So, indeed, use the google-cloud-iam library for doing this.

In addition, your current code don't work because you use an access token to reach Cloud Function.

- Indeed, you have an authorized error (401) -> You present an authorization header, but it's not authorize.
- Without the header, you get a 403 error -> unauthenticated.

Anyway, you need to have a **signed identity token**. You have description and python code snippet [here](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/service-to-service#python)

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how to do do the policy binding in Python?

Comment: Thanks @Dustin-Ingram